# How do I get the everything after this string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've appended a value to my url, so it looks like this now:

```
www.somepage.com&myValue=xxxxx
```

I get my url as follows:

```
var url = document.URL;
```

What I want now is everything after `myValue=`.

What regex would I use to acheive this?

Comment: Use capturing group `myValue=(.*)` , then print the group index 1.

Comment: Try `url.split('myValue=')[1]` , http://jsfiddle.net/0x0e7cc0/ :)

Comment: @AvinashRaj would you have an example of that in action?

Comment: does the input contain a semi-colon?

Comment: @AvinashRaj sorry, no,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like this,

```
> var s = 'www.somepage.com&myValue=xxxxx';
undefined
> var re = /myValue=(.*)/;
undefined
> console.log(re.exec(s)[1])
xxxxx
undefined
> var s = 'www.somepage.com&myValue=xxxxx';
undefined
> s.split('myValue=')[1]
'xxxxx'
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty:

```
//split the url at the "&"
  split_back=(url.split("&"));
//now split the url at the "="
  split_value=(split_back[1].split("="));
```

The value you need is in split_value[1].
check this jsfiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/55rmkx76/2/

Comment: Cheers, there's a comment up above very similar to this.